# USB keyboard won't work in Debian 8

Tags: linux, debian, grub2, bios

Recently I installed debian on a separate drive on my desktop. My keyboard worked in the grub menu but not in the installation menu (I figured this was a fluke and pulled out an old ps/2 keyboard which helped me finish my installation).  Then I booted into the drive and my keyboard worked in grub. I'm then presented with a password prompt to decrypt but the lights on my keyboard flash and it doesn't work. I login using my old keyboard and my regular keyboard still doesn't work inside the OS.

What I tried:

Enabling Intel VT in BIOS,

Enabling legacy support in BIOS,

appending 'noapic' and 'nolapic' on 'linux ...' in grub - side note, I restarted to see if the changes stuck and they weren't there.

Please help, I need this keyboard to work as it is an adaptive keyboard

Comment: What is the brand and model of the keyboard?

Comment: That would be odd but its Aivia k8100. Let me clarify, it's a regular keyboard with a keyguard over it that makes it adaptive

Comment: What does `dmesg` says when you plug/unplug the keyboard?

Comment: This is weird but the media control buttons work but regular input doesn't

Comment: checking /var/log/dmesg after plugging/unplugging shows nothing. running 'dmesg | grep -i usb > unplugged.txt' plugging it in and running 'dmesg | grep -i usb > plugged.txt' gives [http://pastebin.com/tUZecKLZ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch from gaming mode to the normal mode , connect your keyboard and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> , or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>